# apps close automatically while using and back button stops to work meanwhile

Tags: applications

I have a problem with *Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime Plus* that apps are automatically close while using and back button stops to work meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

Try finding out, how many apps currently running when this problem occurs, as this problem can occur when an application is taking too much processing or your temporary memory is full. Try clearing apps from background by hitting the left most button below the screen.